# What is the equivalent of String.Join on TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to create a SQL Server function to “join” multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-sub)

Hi all!

I'm looking for an easy way to concatenate 'n' values. Something like:

```
SELECT MyConcat(',', T.TextColumn)
FROM SomeTable AS T
WHERE T.SomeOtherColumn = SomeCondition
```

So if I have a table like:

```
SomeTable:
Id  | TextColumn | SomeOtherColumn
----+------------+----------------
1   | Qwerty     | Y
2   | qwerty     | N
3   | azerty     | N
4   | Azerty     | Y
```

It would result in something like:

```
SQL:
SELECT MyConcat(';', T.TextColumn)
FROM SomeTable AS T
WHERE T.SomeOtherColumn = 'Y'

RESULT:
'Qwerty;Azerty'
```

Comment: I've found a solution by creating the following function:


    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[JoinTexts]
    (
      @delimiter VARCHAR(20) ,
      @whereClause VARCHAR(1)
    )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
    AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Texts VARCHAR(MAX)

        SELECT  @Texts = COALESCE(@Texts + @delimiter, '') + T.Texto
        FROM    SomeTable AS T
        WHERE   T.SomeOtherColumn = @whereClause

        RETURN @Texts
    END
    GO

Usage:

    SELECT dbo.JoinTexts(' , ', 'Y')

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT
    @Result = CASE
        WHEN @Result IS NULL
        THEN T.TextColumn
        ELSE @Result + ';' + T.TextColumn
    END
FROM
    SomeTable AS T
WHERE
    T.SomeOtherColumn = 'Y';

SELECT @Result
```

Comment: Caution: This will produce unexpected results if any of the values in `textcolumn` are null. To see what I mean, put this under the DECLARE line and run it: `with sometable as (select 'a' as textcolumn, 'y' as someothercolumn
union all select 'b' ,'n'
union all select null, 'y'
union all select 'd', 'y'
) ` -> expecting 'ad', but actual result is 'd', because `null + 'some text'` is `null`. Consider using CONCAT instead, or COALESCE

Answer (score 34):

```
SELECT CAST(TextColumn + ';' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeOtherColumn = 'Y'
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

If you don't like the trailing `;` you can remove the character from the result.

---

EDIT IN 2017

Many platforms now support the windowing function LISTAGG()

Comment: My results were truncated to 2034 results.  I had better luck with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655332/using-sql-server-for-xml-convert-result-datatype-to-text-varchar-string-whate/5658758#5658758

Comment: For SQL Server you can now use `STRING_AGG`. [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: For Oracle and DB2 you can use `LISTAGG()` @aboy021  -- This answer was from over 10 years ago!