# Export SQL Server view to XML inserts undesired CRLF every 2034 characters

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am using the following SP to export a view to a file:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @line varchar(255)
set @line = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM erpSqlBe.dbo.vwPriceListStockxx for xml , root(''daily'')" queryout "d:\myFolder\Daily.xml" -c -CACP -Uyyy -Pzzz '
SELECT @line
EXEC xp_cmdshell @line
```

The resulting file has a CRLF inserted every 2034 characters, making the file unreadable. What is the fix for this ?
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658758/78522), but I don't know how to apply it here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, the solution you're trying to apply is converting the XML data returned by `for xml` to `varchar(max)`. This can be done using `CAST({xml_data} AS VARCHAR(MAX))` like so :

```
set @line = 'bcp "SELECT CAST((SELECT * FROM erpSqlBe.dbo.vwPriceListStockxx for xml , root(''daily'')) AS VARCHAR(MAX))" queryout "d:\myFolder\Daily.xml" -c -CACP -Uyyy -Pzzz '
```

*or* using `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), {xml_data})` :

```
set @line = 'bcp "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), (SELECT * FROM erpSqlBe.dbo.vwPriceListStockxx for xml , root(''daily'')))" queryout "d:\myFolder\Daily.xml" -c -CACP -Uyyy -Pzzz '
```